# Tracking client system ip address

Tags: java, networking, ip

We are launching an ERP application on cloud and hence planning to capture the system ip address of the clients machine who access the application from our server. 
This ip address that we are fetching is it the system ip or localhost ip? 
It is fetched using

```
InetAddress local_ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
InetAddress remote_ip=InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteAddr());
```

Is it secure to fetch the ip address or mac address? As i know the ip address is unique only across a network.

Thank You

Comment: *"Is it secure to fetch the ip address or mac address?"*  Given they can be spoofed, no.  <DWS>Not that this has ever been asked before.</DWS>

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I kno its a repeated question..

Comment: *"I kno its a repeated question.."* Huh.  I put it down to ignorance (regrettable, but forgivable) rather than laziness.

Comment: I'm sorry for the repeated question .. I did research.. The answers were a little confusing hence i wanted to confirm .. I'm not from this background

Comment: Could you please help me out and give me a solution on how to track the client apart from the user name is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to track the mac unless you are on the same network. Once the packet crosses a router the mac addr becomes the mac of the routers you bounce across at each hop. Mac addresses are available to the broadcast domain only. Some devices support proxy arp though.

Comment: Agreed, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses might change over sessions. Think about NATted clients and DHCP assigned addresses. These keep changing. Same IP might represent another client at another time.

Considering security, as mentioned in a comment, no.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Yes Ip address may be repeated over 2 networks.. But what about using the mac address?

Comment: not sure, but how about using a combination of IP and MAC. Just a thought. Do you want to track a client machine or a user? User is identified by the user credentials.

Comment: I want to track the client machine as the user can login from any machine. It is just a measure so that the client doesn't blame us if there is any change in data.

Comment: I think you need to come up with more than one parameters to identify the machine. IP / MAC / OS etc. This is already done on some websites where you can anonymously vote but at the same time cannot vote more than once. But for your case, you need something really concrete to prove your case. You might want to consider authentication using certificates. This does not track the machine but authenticates user on login. But this will make your application a little more complicated. I honestly dont know much about tracking a machine. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you soo much.. I too don know much about this.. Thanks for the help.. i will put these points fwd..